# Reload form in dialog box without page reload

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I have a wordpress page that is using a modal (jQuery UI Dialog) window with a form in it.  The modal works fine, however it has a form in the window with this form tag (content is loaded from a DIV):

```
<form id="inline_ddateform" onSubmit="javascript: return pCalc(this);">
```

When the form is submitted the main page reloads and the variables are coming back in the main site URL.

Before form submit: www.site.com

After form submit: www.site.com?m=4&c=8

How can I bring the variables into the form in the modal with the values that JS is returning?  It's needed to display some info in the modal.

Comment: why don't you use Ajax? no reload..and handled return call as you want? I have no experience with wordpress but it should be a straight forward..

Comment: I don't think WP is a factor, I just mention it for completeness.  I am pretty bound to using this JS code that I've been supplied.

Comment: Not sure why I was voted down for this question but so be it...I think the answer below will get me to where I need to go.

Comment: Because there are a lot of stupid haters out there

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the function here: http://papermashup.com/read-url-get-variables-withjavascript/

It has a function that gets url variables for you.  Copy it into your project then use like so:

```
var variables = getUrlVars()

var m = variables["m"]

alert(m);
```

Then you can use that where you like.